# How to find a Last row in a pivotTable?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to find the last row in a pivotTable named pivotTable1.

```
 Sub lastrowPT ()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim lastRow As Long


    Set pt = Sheet1.PivotTables(1)
    lastRow = pt.TableRange2.Cells(1).row + pt.TableRange2.Rows.count - 1

End sub
```

But I it is nothing working. Any ideas?

Comment: remove the `Sheet1` from the `Sheet1.pt....`

Comment: I did `lastRow = pt.TableRange2.Cells(1).row + pt.TableRange2.Rows.count - 1` but when I use it in the Immediate window I get a error  _run-time'424' Object Required_

Comment: ^ Because `pt` is not `Set` in the Immediate Window.

Comment: I am trying to find the last row to divide it by 6. but I am not getting the correct answer using the lastrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
With Sheet1.PivotTables(1).TableRange2
    LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
End With
```

Last cell on Row2 of the data table:

```
Dim rw As Range
With Sheet1.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange
    Set rw = .Rows(2)
End With
rw.Cells(rw.Cells.Count).Select
```

https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: maybe would you now how I could as well select the last 6 cells up (OFFSET the last cell)?

Comment: Select which cells?  One cell?  The whole row?  You can use `Offset(numRows, numcols)` to locate cells relative to the current range.

Comment: how I could select or active the last cell on the row 2 of the pivot?